# ¿Cómo obtener una lista de números a partir de cadena?

Tags: python, numpy

Tengo una cadena de números de 16300 valores que se encuentran diferenciados por un espacio. Quiero obtener un array de esa cadena de números.

A modo de ejemplo:

```
a = '0 -1 2 3 -2 2 -6'
```

Quiero obtener

```
b = [0,-1,2,3,-2,2,-6]
```

Answer (score 4):

Una cadena de textos puede convertirse fácilmente en un array:

```
import numpy as np

s = "0 -1  2  3  -2  2  -6"
a = np.array(s.split())
a = a.astype(np.integer)
```

Lo primero es usar [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) para separar cada valor por espacio y retornar una lista, los elementos siguen siendo cadenas, por lo que luego de importarlo debemos convertir todos los elementos en este ejemplo a enteros mediante [`astype()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html#numpy-ndarray-astype).

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, es lo que estoy buscando, pero sigo sin poder transformarlo, a modo simple supongamos que tengo:
a= '10 20 30 20' y deseo obtener a=[10,20,30,20]

Comment: @YaGaRa, creo que has planteado mal la pregunta, por tu comentario, entiendo que tienes una cadena de números "10 20 30 20" y la quieres transformar en un array, es así?

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta, es correcto, tengo una cadena de números y deseo obtener un array.

Comment: @YaGaRa, ya edite la respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Efectivamente para separar una cadena por un delimitador, en este caso ' ' puedes usar la función [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) y para obtener una lista de enteros puedes usar la función [int()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) en una list comprehensions de la siguiente manera:

```
a = '0 -1 2 3 -2 2 -6'
a = a.split(' ') 
b = [int(x) for x in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución en forma de función que es mas rápida para listas largas:

```
# a.split() divide el string a una lista
# map aplica a cada elemento la fun "int

def converter(str_num):
return list(map(int,str_num.split()))

converter('0 -1 2 3 -2 2 -6')

Out[1]: 
[0, -1, 2, 3, -2, 2, -6]
```

Comment: Exacto, el separador por defecto en la función split es el espacio asi que se puede omitir. La funcion map devuelve un iterable que se convierte a lista.

Answer (score 0):

Tu ejemplo no funciona, debería ser

```
a = '0 -1 2 3 -2 2 -6'
```

y entonces todo lo que tienes que hacer es:

```
a.split(' ')
```

y obtienes:

```
['0', '-1', '2', '3', '-2', '2', '-6']
```

que por supuesto puedes agregar a otra variable.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero no me funciona tener ['0','-1','2'] deseo solo obtener [0,-1,-2] sin las comillas simples